# IR Receiver gives invalid start pulse with screen attached, nothing without screen

Tags: sensor, pi-pico

I am trying to display the value of an IR signal on a [screen](https://thepihut.com/products/1-3-ips-lcd-display-module-for-raspberry-pi-pico-240x240) using a Pico and an [IR sensor](https://thepihut.com/products/ir-sensor), but with the screen attached to the Pico and the output of the sensor on GPIO pin 4, the printed value is an error stating "Invalid start pulse". When the screen is removed, nothing is printed at all when a value should be printed in both cases. Here is my code:

```
from machine import Pin, freq
from ir_rx.print_error import print_error
from ir_rx.nec import NEC_8

pin_ir = Pin(4, Pin.IN)

# User callback
def callback(data, addr, ctrl):
    if data < 0:  # NEC protocol sends repeat codes.
        pass
    else:
        print(decodeKeyValue(data))

ir = NEC_8(pin_ir, callback)  # Instantiate receiver
ir.error_function(print_error)  # Show debug information

try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ir.close()
```

Comment: Nothing is printed WHERE when the screen is removed? Where do you expect it to be displayed? Is the whole program's output being written to a file for logging? I have had issues on headless systems when a library expects a screen/keyboard/mouse but you dont have those, it will cause a crash on startup.

Comment: As far as the "Invalid start pulse" have you googled that along with the library name? I would suspect that either a web search, or looking at the source code would at least tell you what the error message means (what defines an invalid start pulse) along with maybe ways to fix the issue.

Comment: perhaps the screen uses pin 4 for something ...